# Loading album art makes scrolling laggy and jarring in jetpack compose

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing an offline music player app and there's a track list where I use the lazy column to display the track list.

Also I use Coil's AsyncImage function to load the image. There's the code,

```
LazyColumn(
       modifier = Modifier.consumeWindowInsets(innerPadding),
       contentPadding = innerPadding
){
  items(count = listMusic.size){
       MusicRow(listMusic[it])
       }
 }
```

And Here's the MusicRow function,

```
@Composable
fun MusicRow(music : Music){
    Row(
        Modifier
            .clickable {
                // TODO : Music click event
            }
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(72.dp)
            .padding(vertical = 8.dp, horizontal = 16.dp),
    ){
        Box(
            Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
        ){
            AsyncImage(
                model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                    .data(music.imagePath?.let { getAlbumArt(LocalContext.current, it) })
                    .crossfade(false)
                    .build(),
                placeholder = painterResource(R.drawable.default_album_art),
                contentDescription = "Album art",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(1f)
            )
        }

        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(start = 16.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = music.title,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                maxLines = 1
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
            Text(
                text = music.artist,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                maxLines = 1
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I also created a getAlbumArt function which basically get the music URL and return the album art as a Bitmap. Note that, The asycImage uses the getAlbumArt function. [I think it's a terrible way to do.]

Here's the code,

```
fun getAlbumArt(context: Context, uri: Uri): Bitmap {
    val mmr = MediaMetadataRetriever()
    mmr.setDataSource(context, uri)
    val data = mmr.embeddedPicture
    return if(data != null){
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.size)

    }else{
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.default_album_art)
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the list is lagged so much while scrolling. I also tried to build a signed APK in release mode, but the problem is still there.

I think I'm not using the full potential of the coil's library or there's a better way to do it. Help me guys the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there is no problem with your code! It is common for Jetpack Compose apps to experience lag or performance issues when running in debug mode. This is because debug mode enables additional checks and instrumentation that can impact performance. The performance of Jetpack Compose apps typically improves significantly when running in release mode.
Test your code in release mode, And everything works fine!
To change the debug mode to release mode and vice versa, Open **Select Build Variant...** form **Build** menu. This window will appear :

[image]

Click on `debug` and change it to `release`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Items` of LazyColumn , use `item` , like shown below

```
LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.consumeWindowInsets(innerPadding),
            contentPadding = innerPadding
        ) {
            listMusic.forEach { music ->
                item(music.id) {
                    MusicRow(music)
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why this solution should resolve the lagging?

Comment: Right, It didn't work.