# Android Compose Custom GridCalendar HorizontalPager paging Performance

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm making Casutom Calendar with compose.

Display the month-long calendar with LazyVerticalGrid and show the next or previous calendar when paged with HorizontalPager.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun CalendarPager(
    todayClicked: (LocalDate) -> Unit,
    pagedMonth: (LocalDate) -> Unit,
){
    val yearRange = IntRange(1970, 2100)
    val initialPage = (LocalDate.now().year - yearRange.first) * 12 + LocalDate.now().monthValue - 1
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = initialPage) {
        (yearRange.last - yearRange.first) * 12 // 모든 년도의 월 수 만큼 pageCount
    }

    HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) { page ->
        val month = LocalDate.of(
            yearRange.first + pagerState.currentPage / 12,
            pagerState.currentPage % 12 + 1,
            1
        )
        pagedMonth.invoke(month)

        val displayDate by remember {
            derivedStateOf {
                LocalDate.of(
                    yearRange.first + page / 12,
                    page % 12 + 1,
                    1
                )
            }
        }

        TestGrid(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 10.dp),
            calendarDate = displayDate,
            onSelectDate = todayClicked
        )
    }.also {
        DlogUtil.d(MyTag, "Recomposition Check HorizontalPager")
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestGrid(
    modifier: Modifier,
    calendarDate: LocalDate,

    onSelectDate: (LocalDate) -> Unit
) {

    val lastDay = calendarDate.lengthOfMonth()
    val days = IntRange(1, lastDay).toList()
    
    val firstDayOfWeek = calendarDate.dayOfWeek.value
    val lastDayColumn = (firstDayOfWeek + lastDay - 1) % 7
    
    val afterBoxCount = 7 - lastDayColumn - 1
    
    
    val totalGridCount = if (firstDayOfWeek == 7)
        0
    else
        firstDayOfWeek + days.size + afterBoxCount
    
    
    val boxHeight = if (totalGridCount > 35) {
        45.dp
    } else {
        54.dp
    }

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = modifier,
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(7)
    ) {
        
        if (firstDayOfWeek != 7) {
            repeat(firstDayOfWeek) {
                item {
                    EmptyDay(boxHeight)
                }
            }
        }

        items(days) { day ->
            val date = calendarDate.withDayOfMonth(day)

            TestDay(
                height = boxHeight,
                displayDate = date,
                isToday = date == LocalDate.now(),
                isSelected = false,
                onSelectDate = onSelectDate
            )
        }
        
        repeat(afterBoxCount) {
            item {
                EmptyDay(boxHeight)
            }
        }
    }.also {
        DlogUtil.d(MyTag, "Recomposition Check TestGrid")
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestDay(
    height: Dp,
    displayDate: LocalDate,
    isToday: Boolean,
    isSelected: Boolean,

    onSelectDate: (LocalDate) -> Unit
) {
    val dayOfWeek = displayDate.dayOfWeek

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(height)
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
            .calendarBorder(isSelected)                    // 선택 Day Gray Border
            .noRippleClickable { onSelectDate(displayDate) },
        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(18.dp)
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(top = 2.dp)
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                .calendarBackground(isToday, getTodayBgColor(dayOfWeek)),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = displayDate.dayOfMonth.toString(),
                color = getTextColor(isToday, dayOfWeek),
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
        }
    }.also {
        DlogUtil.d(MyTag, "Recomposition Check TestDay Box")
    }
}
```

I'm drawing a view so that the calendar comes out with Grid.
However, it seems that the performance is not good when paging.

Is this the wrong way to organize the calendar?

Am I trying to draw too many views?

Comment: Your code is fine check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77537546/7756492

Comment: Does it make such a big difference?  It's so smooth and works so well.
I want to adopt your comment.
Could you please write it as an answer?