# The nested lazyRow is not scroll smoothly in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a LazyColumn and a LazyRow inside it. when I want to scroll the lazyRow, it doesn't scroll smoothly, when I scroll it to the left and want to scroll to the right without taking my finger, the scrolling stops in a position and I must take my finger and move the list back and forth again to scroll.

https://file.io/XSNKzlahQEmV

```
val lazyState = rememberLazyListState()
    Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        if (uiState.isLoading)
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        else
            Column(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(48.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                            .width(60.dp)
                            .padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopEnd
                    ) {
                        MediumContentText(
                            text = stringResource(R.string.time),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge.copy(
                                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline,
                                fontSize = 12.sp
                            ),
                        )
                    }
                    VerticalDivider(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                    )
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
                        ) {
                            MediumContentText(
                                text = stringResource(R.string.schedule),
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge.copy(
                                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline,
                                    fontSize = 12.sp
                                ),
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                HorizontalDivider()
                LazyColumn(
                    state = lazyState,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
                ) {
                    itemsIndexed(uiState.orders ?: emptyList()) { _, item ->
                        val startTime = item?.visitAt.convertToTimeZone()
                        val endTime = item?.visitAt.addHours(3)

                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(160.dp),
                            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
                        ) {
                            Column(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .width(60.dp)
                                    .fillMaxHeight()
                                    .padding(10.dp),
                                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
                                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                            ) {
                                startTime?.let {
                                    MediumContentText(
                                        text = "${
                                            it.time.hour
                                        }:${
                                            it.time.minute
                                        }".formatTimeWithTwoNumber(),
                                    )
                                }
                                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                                endTime?.let {
                                    MediumContentText(
                                        text = "${it.time.hour}:${it.time.minute}".formatTimeWithTwoNumber(),
                                        style = TextStyle(
                                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline,
                                            fontSize = 12.sp
                                        )
                                    )
                                }
                            }

                            VerticalDivider(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxHeight()
                            )

                            LazyRow(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .height(160.dp)
                                    .padding(vertical = 4.dp),
                                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                                contentPadding = PaddingValues(4.dp)
                            ) {
                                items(
                                    uiState.orders ?: emptyList()
                                ) { item ->
                                    Surface(
                                        modifier = modifier.width(250.dp),
                                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
                                        shadowElevation = 8.dp,
                                        color = if (item?.status == "done" || item?.status == "cancel") MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary else MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
                                    ) {
                                        ScheduleRow(
                                            item = item,
                                            onClick = { onNavigateToDetail(item) }
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        HorizontalDivider()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Saeed Jan, Your code is fine check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77537546/7756492

Comment: @ucMedia I have isuue in the release and debug mode. It's not a compose lag, when I scroll to the left the lazyRow will be locked and I have to try several time to scroll again

Comment: I added the video link

Comment: Unfortunately your video has been deleted